# Slds Button With Icon

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I'm using the `lightning-button-icon` inside the SLDS button.(Reason : to Change the button color).

[image]

button icon is in grey color `variant="container"` how to change the `forward` button color to white.

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" style=" border: none;background-color: #04844B;color: white;">Next
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:forward"  variant="container" alternative-text="Settings" title="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: Try inverse variant

Comment: inverse variant adding border in Icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the other simple way by embedding icon in the lightning-button

```
<lightning-button variant="success" label="Next" title="Next" icon-name="utility:forward" icon-position="right" class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

More information : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/example

```
                                 OR
```

In your case : Use `variant="bare-inverse"` in `lightning-button-icon`

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" style=" border: none;background-color: #04844B;color: white;">Next
<lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:forward"  variant="bare-inverse" alternative-text="Settings" title="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: I want to have some custom color in this button

Comment: Please see the updated answer then

Comment: Thanks, It's working as expect. :)